# Mouse over the <a> tag

Tags: javascript

There is a prompt in the lower left corner When I put the mouse over the  tag,
and can u tell me how to forbid this phenomenon.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3mR8.jpg)

Comment: Use a button and on click redirect using `JS`

Comment: Can you elaborate on it? thank u

Comment: The prompt you are talking about is a browser feature that allows user to peek the url the anchor tag is linking. To avoid this, you can mimic anchor's behaviour with a button. You will find *how to* easily by searching.

Comment: I think I have understand your meaning, but my page has a lot of <a> tag, certainly not one by one to set up?

Comment: Why do you wish to do this?

Comment: Because I am now doing a product,it's running under the PC browser and it's a touch screen .Our boss does not want the browser to appear in the lower left corner of the tips

Comment: I just looked at it, if I use the method you said before, with <button> to replace the words, my page will have a lot of changes, which is obviously not desirable. Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

As commented, the behaviour that you wish to stop is a browser's feature.

To avoid this, you will have to simulate anchor's behaviour on your own but as you said you have many anchors and you cannot manually convert them to buttons, you can try following code:

```js
function maskAnchors() {
  var els = document.querySelectorAll('a[href]');
  console.log("Anchors Found: ", els.length)
  for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    els[i].setAttribute("data-url", els[i].getAttribute('href'));
    els[i].removeAttribute("href");
    els[i].addEventListener("click", handleClick)
  }
}

function handleClick() {
  var url = this.getAttribute('data-url');
  window.open(url)
}

document.getElementById('btnAdd').addEventListener("click", function() {
  var container = document.querySelector('.content');
  var link = document.createElement('a')
  link.href = "www.google.com";
  link.textContent = "This is a newly added link";
  container.append(link)
})

document.getElementById('btnMask').addEventListener("click", maskAnchors)

window.addEventListener('load', maskAnchors)
```

```css
.maskedAnchor {
  color: -webkit-link;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <a href="google.com">Google</a>
  <a href="Facebook.com">Facebook</a>
  <a href="StackOverflow.com">StackOverflow</a>
  <a href="YouTube.com">YouTube</a>
  <a href="Example.com">Example</a>
  <a>blabla</a>
</div>
<button id="btnAdd">Add Anchor</button>
<button id="btnMask">Run masking</button>
```

**Note:**

- Removing `href` will change styling. You will also have to do that manually.
- This will not handle any anchors added dynamically after execution of this function. You will have to call this function again. I have optimised function to only fetch anchors that has `href`

Hope it helps!

Comment: oh my god!
I must say that your method makes me find a lot of inspiration,but it's a bit not meet the reality of my product needs...
But I really thank you very much, thank you, my friend, can you be a friend? I am from China, do you have a wechat or qq?
You also can email me: 15555602203@163.com or 1163085878@qq.com

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help you in some way. :-)